# Spring integration: Using cusom header for http:outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: rest, http, http-headers, spring-integration, http-put

I have a situation to use a `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter ... />` to send an object with information stored in the header.

Following works when I call the `<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter ... />` like follows:

```
public void openTicket(final Profile profile, final Ticket ticket) {
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("profile", profile.toString());
    final HttpEntity<Ticket> entity = new HttpEntity<Ticket>(ticket, headers);
    template.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, Ticket.class);
}
```

This calls my inboung-channel-adapter successful with the given profile in the headers:

```
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="api_app_integration_request_channel" 
    supported-methods="PUT" 
    path="/process/ticket"
    request-payload-type="*.model.Ticket"
    mapped-request-headers="profile"
    error-channel="internal-client-rest-ticket-error-channel"
>
    <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" />
</int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

What doesnt work is calling the service via outbound-channel-adapter, the call itself works, but my header 'profile' is gone.

```
<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="client_rest_ticket_outbound_channel"
    http-method="PUT"
    url="http://localhost:8080/process/ticket"
    mapped-request-headers="profile"
/>
```

I am using **Spring-Boot 1.3.6.RELEASE**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom headers are (currently) mapped with an `X-` prefix by default; to map them without the prefix you need to wire up a `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` with `userDefinedHeaderPrefix` set to null (or `""`) as well as the outbound header name(s) you want to map.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping).

**EDIT:**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper" id="headerMapper"
    p:userDefinedHeaderPrefix=""
    p:inboundHeaderNames="profile"
    p:outboundHeaderNames="profile"
/>
```

Comment: Hey Gary, thanks for your response. What is considered as good practice? I guess keeping 'X-' prefix. Is it used for marking custom header keys or what is the mean of 'X-'?

Comment: I believe the original intent was to avoid collisions with future standard headings. I seem to recall that the current thinking us to not prefix custom headers so we are thinking of changing the default in 5.0.

Comment: Thanks Gary, cos I cant format code in comments I edited your answer with the configuration I did. Hope thats okay